# returning character array from function

Tags: c

I'm trying to return a char array from a function. According to everything I have read I understand I cannot return the array itself because arrays are second class citizens. But from what I understand I can create a pointer to it and make it static. I have tried both and am failing to compile. Any ideas why?

```
int main ()
{
  char *hold_array[] = get_array ();                                                              
  return 0;
}

char *get_array (void)
{
   static char *array[] = {"test1", "test2"};
   return (array);
}
```

Comment: Two problems: 1, `hold_array` and the return value of `get_array` should be `char **`, not `char *`. 2, `char_array()` has to be declared before `main()` or it will be assumed to return `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*hold_array[]` is an array of pointers. The function `get_array` returns a single pointer, albeit that the returned pointer is a pointer to an array of `char *` pointers. However, you cannot declare `*hold_array[]` as an array of pointers without any dimension. The compiler has no idea how much space to allocate for it. It doesn't know how many pointers you'll need.

You can declare it as `**hold_array`. This is a single pointer which points to an array of pointers. I know it sounds the same, but it isn't exactly. In the case of `*hold_array[]` you are allocating multiple pointers and therefore need a dimension. In the case of `**hold_array` you are allocating one pointer which points to an array of pointers. In your initializer `static char *array[]` the compiler sees you need two pointers and internally dimensions it for you as `*array[2]`.

Therefore in `main()` you are asking the compiler to create an array of unknown dimension which consists of `char *` pointers. The function `get_array` returns the address of an array of pointers, but not the individual pointers within the array. Remember that `array[0]` is a pointer to the string `"test1"` and `array[1]` is a pointer to the string `"test2"`. The strings themselves are character arrays with a 0 byte at the end.

Another way to think of it is:

```
char *test1 = "test1";
char *test2 = "test2";

char *array[2];
char **hold_array;

array[0] = test1;
array[1] = test2;

hold_array = array;

printf("\n%s = %s", hold_array[0], array[0]);  //print the same string
```

Therefore, when you return `array` the compiler assumes you mean the array itself since you haven't otherwise specified a member of the array. So only the address of `array` itself is returned. This is identical to `**hold_array`. Which means `hold_array = array`. `**hold_array` is a single pointer which points to an array of pointers. `array[2]` is an array of pointers which allocated space for 2 pointers.

Answer (score 2):

compile error because of type mismatch. @JustinPeel points out that `const` is needed too.

```
int main(void)
{
    char **hold_array = get_array ();
    return 0;
}

char **get_array(void)
{
     static const char *array[] = {"test1", "test2"};
     return (array);
}
```

Comment: This compiles with warnings for me because you then have non-const pointers to a string literal. The OP should really either change the chars to const chars or use a helper function that uses mallocs. My guess is that these strings really are supposed to be const.

Comment: @JustinPeel You are right, this is not a good practice, using `malloc` is a better solution generally.

Comment: it is perfectly fine to use do `static const char *array[] = {"test1", test2"};` too though.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
char *hold_array[] = get_array ();
```

to

```
char **hold_array = get_array ();
```

Or (better still IHMO) to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do it is best to allocate the array dynamically using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and then return a pointer to the allocated memory.

E.g.:

`char* char_array_ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_array);`

Do note that `sizeof(char)` is redundant since the `char` type is guaranteed to be 1 by the standard, though you will need `sizeof` for other types.

You function should have a signature similar to `char* return_array()` and you should return the pointer to the allocated memory at the end of the function - `return array_ptr;`

All in all we would have something like:

```
char* allocate_array()
{
    char* ptr = malloc(20); /* size here will be 20 */

    strcpy(ptr, "Just a normal string."); /* copy string to that pointer */

    return ptr; /* return pointer for further use */
}
```

Don't forget to [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) the memory allocated with `malloc` once you're done using it.